# Getting a popup to fadeOut on its own with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I am attempting to get a pop up to close with a setTimeout function instead of actually having to close it with the close button. I am wanting the timeout time to start once the popup appears.

I tried to do it (the commented out code) and it just kills the script.

What am I doing wrong?

Instead of the click function, what can I use to get this popup to show in a success of an ajax call?

```js
$(function() {
    //----- OPEN
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 
    //----- CLOSE
     
  $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
  
  
/*   setTimeout(function() {
('.newsletter-popup').hide();,4000 );
});*/
```

```css
/* Outer */
.newsletter-popup {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
 
/* Inner */
.popup-inner {
    max-width:700px;
    width:90%;
    padding:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#fff;
}
 
/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    padding-top:4px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    transition:ease 0.25s all;
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    border-radius:1000px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100%;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
.popup-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-decoration:none;
}
#popup-inner-content {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Open Popup #1</a>
 
<div class="newsletter-popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <div id="popup-inner-content">Thanks for subscribing to our newsletter!</div>
       <!--   <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p> -->
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a delayed fadeout when you open your popup so that it fades out automatically after a delay. [Working jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/305sbw4x/)

```
$('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350).delay(4000).fadeOut(350);
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what I could do for this "Instead of the click function, what can I use to get this popup to show in a success of an ajax call?"

Comment: Add this in your ajax success callback function: $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

Comment: Doing that I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: targeted_popup_class is not defined`

Comment: I added my variable `var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');`, but it still won't even open.

Comment: @Paul Add this in your ajax callback instead: `$('.newsletter-popup').fadeOut(350);`

Comment: @Paul Ah, sorry, I misread your first comment. You wanted to _open_ the popup. Just change fadeOut to fadeIn

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your setTimeout function.

It should look like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('.newsletter-popup').hide();
}, 4000);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It won't allow my popup to open up.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    //----- OPEN
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
 setTimeout(function(){
$('.newsletter-popup').fadeOut();
}, 2000);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 
    //----- CLOSE
     
  $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut();
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
/* Outer */
.newsletter-popup {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
 
/* Inner */
.popup-inner {
    max-width:700px;
    width:90%;
    padding:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#fff;
}
 
/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    padding-top:4px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    transition:ease 0.25s all;
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    border-radius:1000px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100%;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
.popup-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-decoration:none;
}
#popup-inner-content {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Open Popup #1</a>
 
<div class="newsletter-popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <div id="popup-inner-content">Thanks for subscribing to our newsletter!</div>
       <!--   <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p> -->
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to have to click to close it. I want it to do it on its own.